# How to find the change in value between subsequent groups from an initial group in R?

Tags: r

I want to find the change of the height at each id for each event (B,C,D) from the initial event (A). For example, the change of A1 to B1 is 5 or A1 to C1 is 11.

```
df <- data.frame(event=c(rep('A',4),rep('B',4),rep('C',4),rep('D',4)), id=rep(1:4,4),height = c(1,4,2,4,6,8,9,6,12,15,13,16,21,24,26,24))
    event id height
1      A  1      1
2      A  2      4
3      A  3      2
4      A  4      4
5      B  1      6
6      B  2      8
7      B  3      9
8      B  4      6
9      C  1     12
10     C  2     15
11     C  3     13
12     C  4     16
13     D  1     21
14     D  2     24
15     D  3     26
16     D  4     24
```

To try to answer this I made a separate dataframe of just initial event points and then subtracted them from each event group.

```
df_a <- filter(df,event =="A") # filtered only initial event points

df %>%
  group_by(event) %>% # grouped events
  mutate(growth = height - df_a$height) # subtracted grouped event points by the initial event 


   event    id height growth
 1 A         1      1      0
 2 A         2      4      0
 3 A         3      2      0
 4 A         4      4      0
 5 B         1      6      5
 6 B         2      8      4
 7 B         3      9      7
 8 B         4      6      2
 9 C         1     12     11
10 C         2     15     11
11 C         3     13     11
12 C         4     16     12
13 D         1     21     20
14 D         2     24     20
15 D         3     26     24
16 D         4     24     20
```

But I am worried about duplicate, missing, or mistyped events or IDs that might throw off this vectored approach. I need suggestions on how to confirm that I will find the correct change for each respective ID. (A1 to B1, C1, or D1) and (A2 to B2, C2, D2) and so on.

Can I do this with looping? I am not very confident with looping but could looping accomplish this by confirming that only matching IDs can be used?

Or how can I confirm that every initial ID has a respective ID(or NA) at each event so the vectored approach will work 100% of the time.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a grouping by 'id' and then subtract from subsetting the 'height' where 'event' is 'A'.  Just to avoid for any missing values use `in%` instead of `==` (as `%in%` returns FALSE for NA whereas `==` returns NA) and also, after the subset, get the first element (`[1]`) in case there are duplicates

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(growth =  height - height[event %in% 'A'][1]) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 16 x 4
   event    id height growth
   <chr> <int>  <int>  <int>
 1 A         1      1      0
 2 A         2      4      0
 3 A         3      2      0
 4 A         4      4      0
 5 B         1      6      5
 6 B         2      8      4
 7 B         3      9      7
 8 B         4      6      2
 9 C         1     12     11
10 C         2     15     11
11 C         3     13     11
12 C         4     16     12
13 D         1     21     20
14 D         2     24     20
15 D         3     26     24
16 D         4     24     20
```

---

We can also test where there are no 'A's in a 'id'

```
> df %>% 
+     slice(-1) %>%  # removed the first row
+     group_by(id) %>% 
+     mutate(growth =  height - height[event %in% 'A'][1]) %>%
+     ungroup
# A tibble: 15 x 4
   event    id height growth
   <chr> <int>  <int>  <int>
 1 A         2      4      0
 2 A         3      2      0
 3 A         4      4      0
 4 B         1      6     NA # note the NAs for those cases
 5 B         2      8      4
 6 B         3      9      7
 7 B         4      6      2
 8 C         1     12     NA
 9 C         2     15     11
10 C         3     13     11
11 C         4     16     12
12 D         1     21     NA
13 D         2     24     20
14 D         3     26     24
15 D         4     24     20
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(event = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D"), id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), height = c(1L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 12L, 15L, 13L, 16L, 21L, 24L, 26L, 
24L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16"))
```

Comment: @pabstack It may be better to check the [vignettes](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) as it would be the most updated reference.  Then, as in any other programming, I would say practise, make mistakes, debug and learn from it.  When I say practise, you can take any solved program in base R programming and try to convert to tidyverse (or from other languages)

Comment: @pabstack also, once you are familiar, you may also contribute to SO by answering questions.  It may not work for everybody due to the social pressure, but it is a great way of learning due to the game part

Answer (score 1):

We can use `match` which will return the 1st `height` value where `event = 'A'` in each group. If in a group there is no `'A'` event, it will return `NA`.

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(height_res = height - height[match('A', event)]) %>%
  ungroup

#   event    id height height_res
#   <chr> <int>  <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1 A         1      1          0
# 2 A         2      4          0
# 3 A         3      2          0
# 4 A         4      4          0
# 5 B         1      6          5
# 6 B         2      8          4
# 7 B         3      9          7
# 8 B         4      6          2
# 9 C         1     12         11
#10 C         2     15         11
#11 C         3     13         11
#12 C         4     16         12
#13 D         1     21         20
#14 D         2     24         20
#15 D         3     26         24
#16 D         4     24         20
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here are two approaches which append the `growth` column *by reference*, i.e. without copying the whole dataset.

#### Undisturbed dataset

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, growth := height - first(height[event == "A"]), by = id]
```

which updates `df` *in place*:

```
df
```

> ```
>     event id height growth
>  1:     A  1      1      0
>  2:     A  2      4      0
>  3:     A  3      2      0
>  4:     A  4      4      0
>  5:     B  1      6      5
>  6:     B  2      8      4
>  7:     B  3      9      7
>  8:     B  4      6      2
>  9:     C  1     12     11
> 10:     C  2     15     11
> 11:     C  3     13     11
> 12:     C  4     16     12
> 13:     D  1     21     20
> 14:     D  2     24     20
> 15:     D  3     26     24
> 16:     D  4     24     20
> ```

or

```
setDT(df)[, growth := height - height[chmatch("A", event)], by = id][]
```

which updates `df` likewise.

#### Disturbed dataset

Now, let's see how this will work with a disturbed data set where

- id 3 is missing from event A
- id 2 is duplicated in event A (just like a typo in row 3)
- row 5 (B1) is missing

```
df2 <- setDT(df)[3, id := 2][-5]
df2
```

> ```
>     event id height growth
>  1:     A  1      1      0
>  2:     A  2      4      0
>  3:     A  2      2      0 
>  4:     A  4      4      0
>  5:     B  2      8      4
>  6:     B  3      9      7
>  7:     B  4      6      2
>  8:     C  1     12     11
>  9:     C  2     15     11
> 10:     C  3     13     11
> 11:     C  4     16     12
> 12:     D  1     21     20
> 13:     D  2     24     20
> 14:     D  3     26     24
> 15:     D  4     24     20
> ```

Both approaches

```
df2[, growth := height - first(height[event == "A"]), by = id]
```

or

```
df2[, growth := height - height[chmatch("A", event)], by = id]
```

modify `df2` in the same way:

```
df2
```

> ```
>     event id height growth
>  1:     A  1      1      0
>  2:     A  2      4      0
>  3:     A  2      2     -2
>  4:     A  4      4      0
>  5:     B  2      8      4
>  6:     B  3      9     NA
>  7:     B  4      6      2
>  8:     C  1     12     11
>  9:     C  2     15     11
> 10:     C  3     13     NA
> 11:     C  4     16     12
> 12:     D  1     21     20
> 13:     D  2     24     20
> 14:     D  3     26     NA
> 15:     D  4     24     20
> ```

#### Data

```
df <- data.frame(
  event = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 4),
  id = rep(1:4, 4),
  height = c(1, 4, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 6, 12, 15, 13, 16, 21, 24, 26, 24)
)
```